# API call in argo Workflows

Tags: argo-workflows

How can I trigger argo workflows via an API-Call? I found this
[example for API Call with ARGO](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/rest-examples/).

I see my workflows in argo under the URL

https://argo.companyName-eap.net/applications/inte-tsopbms-workflows?view=tree&resource=

So I tried the API call at the end of the post based on the example, with three different urls

- https://workflows.companyName-eap.net/api
- https://workflows.companyName-eap.net/api/events
- https://workflows.companyName-eap.net/api/events/inte-tsopbms

but always get the result

```
{"code":12,"message":"Not Implemented"}
```

Where is the API implemented and how can I call it?

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://workflows.companyName-eap.net/api/v1 \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "namespace": "inte-tsopbms",
  "serverDryRun": false,
  "workflow": {
      "metadata": {
        "generateName": "hello-world-",
        "namespace": "inte-tsopbms",
        "labels": {
          "workflows.argoproj.io/completed": "false"
         }
      },
     "spec": {
       "templates": [
        {
         "name": "whalesay",
         "arguments": {},
         "inputs": {},
         "outputs": {},
         "metadata": {},
         "container": {
          "name": "",
          "image": "docker/whalesay:latest",
          "command": [
            "cowsay"
          ],
          "args": [
            "hello world"
          ],
          "resources": {}
        }
      }
    ],
    "entrypoint": "whalesay",
    "arguments": {}
  }
}
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is implemented in [Argo Server](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/argo-server/).
You need to configure a suitable [Auth mode](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/argo-server-auth-mode/).
Also take a look at [how to generate an Access Token](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/access-token/).